# We say that linkedlist is not an indexed based collection, why?

Tags: data-structures, arraylist, linked-list

I am not able to figure out the difference between linkedlist and arraylist. The below implementation confuses me more. Uptil now I was assuming that LinkedList is not an indexed based datastructure.

```
package com.rnd.core.collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class LinkedListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
        myLinkedList.add("Spring");
        myLinkedList.add("Struts");
        myLinkedList.add("EJB");
        myLinkedList.add("Hibernate");
        myLinkedList.add(1, "Collections");
        myLinkedList.add(1, "JMS");

        System.out.println(""+myLinkedList.subList(1, 3));
        System.out.println("Search result for \"Hibernate\":" + myLinkedList.contains("Hibernate"));
        System.out.println("Search result for \"Hibernate\":" + myLinkedList.contains("ibatis"));
        for(String item: myLinkedList){
            System.out.println(item.toString());    
        }

        System.out.println("<><>"+myLinkedList.get(1));

        List<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        myArrayList.add("Spring");
        myArrayList.add("Struts");
        myArrayList.add("EJB");
        myArrayList.add("Hibernate");
        myArrayList.add(1, "Collections");
        myArrayList.add(1, "JMS");

        myArrayList.subList(1, 2);
        System.out.println("*****************"+myArrayList.subList(1, 3));

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the underlying implementation. An array is a fixed-size block of memory divided into chunks, with each chunk holding one element. It's easy to jump to any individual element using its index number, and modifying one element does not affect the rest of the array. Adding an element to an array is expensive, because you essentially need to copy the entire array into a larger space to make room for the new element. (Adding to the end of the array can be made faster by preallocating more space than you actually need, but eventually you would need to copy the entire array again.)

A linked list, on the other hand, is made of independent blocks of memory, each of which contains the element to store and a pointer to the next item in the list. Adding to such a list (given a pointer to the location where you want to add) is fast, because you just need to grab a new block of memory and modify the pointers of a small number of nodes, independent of the size of the list as a whole. The cost is that in order to *get* a pointer to an arbitrary node in the middle, you need to walk the length of the list from the beginning.

This is a bit of a simplification, but the main idea is that each underlying data type is suitable for different applications of the abstract concept of a "list", and you need to consider the types of operations (lookups, additions, deletions, etc) you want to perform before choosing which is more suitable.